# Do APNS push notifications work after removing an app from the App store?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, apple-push-notifications

I am in the process from transitioning an iOS app from one developer account to another. The original app uses APNS push notifications extensively, and wouldn't be very useful were they to stop.

To remove confusion about app duplication and rights, I am planning on marking the original app as 'Developer Removed from Sale' in iTunesConnect while the new app is in the review process.

Later, I will submit an update to the original app which points the old users to the new app in the App Store.

My question is: If I mark an app as removed from sale, will my existing APNS notifications continue to work for people who have already downloaded the old application? Note: I am not *deleting* the application, merely marking it as not for sale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the application hasn't changed of appId on the same Apple account, notifications will continue to work, if the certificate is not revoked, or expired.

Comment: Production APN certificates expire after 1 year.  If you can transition your users to the new app before this happens, you should be fine; if not, you may lose the ability to send to apps created under the deprecated account.

Comment: Is there any official documentation claiming the same?